# I am facing an error at "Line: 12, Column: 1 System.TypeException: Invalid integer" Could you please help?

Tags: apex, error, developer-console

```
public class ValidateSIN {
    public static boolean IsCanadianSIN(string sSIN){

    Integer iChecksum = 0;
    Integer iDigit = 0;

    // Checking if number is not starting with 9
    if(!sSIN.startsWith('9')){
        for (Integer i = 0; i < sSIN.length(); i++){
            // even number else odd
            if ((Math.Mod((i+1),2)) == 0){
                iDigit = Integer.Valueof(sSIN.Substring(i, 1))*2; //***throws error at this line
                iChecksum += (iDigit < 10) ? iDigit : iDigit - 9;
            } else {
                iChecksum += Integer.Valueof(sSIN.Substring(i, 1));
            }
        }

        if(Math.Mod(iChecksum,10) == 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String.substring returns the string between *startIndex* (inclusive) and *endIndex* (exclusive). Since you specify 1 as the second parameter, this effectively returns an empty string:

```
System.debug('hello'.substring(2,1)); // outputs empty string
```

How I've done this in the past is to split the string, and then iterate over that.

```
public boolean IsCanadianSIN(string sSIN){
    Integer iChecksum = 0;
    String[] digits = sSIN.split('');
    Boolean isEven = false;
    if(digits[0] == '9') {
        return false;
    }
    for(String digit: digits) {
        Integer iDigit = Integer.valueOf(digit) * (isEven? 2: 1);
        iDigit = iDigit < 10? iDigit: iDigit - 9;
        isEven = !isEven;
        iChecksum += iDigit;
    }
    return Math.mod(iChecksum, 10) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per sf documentation on [String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

> substring(startIndex, endIndex) -
> Returns a new String that begins with the character at the specified zero-based startIndex and extends to the character at endIndex - 1

you need to edit your code in those lines to have

```
sSIN.substring(i, i + 1)
```

This is the working snippet.

```
String sSIN = '1233123122';
Integer iChecksum = 0;
Integer iDigit = 0;

// Checking if number is not starting with 9
if(!sSIN.startsWith('9')){
    for (Integer i = 0; i < sSIN.length(); i++){
        // even number else odd
        if ((Math.mod((i+1),2)) == 0){
//            System.debug(i);
            System.debug(sSIN.substring(i, i +1));
            iDigit = Integer.valueOf(sSIN.substring(i, i + 1))*2; //***throws error at this line
            iChecksum += (iDigit < 10) ? iDigit : iDigit - 9;
        } else {
            iChecksum += Integer.valueOf(sSIN.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
    }

    if(Math.mod(iChecksum,10) == 0){
        System.debug(true);
    } else {
        System.debug(false);
    }

} else {
    System.debug(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am again facing this error, "Line: 16, Column: 1
System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds: 1"
COuld you please help resolve this?

Comment: updated my answer